# Java - Thread Not Handling a Retrofit w/ Realm Database

Tags: java, android, realm, retrofit, rx-java

My problem happened when I was trying to get data from the API using retrofit and save it in realm db. NOTE: This step works well and the data saves in the 'objectrealm'. But when I tried to handle the thread to keep the API syn working in the background nothing happens, I tried changing the data but the realm.onChange does not update the log.

This is my code:

Presenter layer:

```
 compositeDisposable.add(INSTANCE_API_SERVICE.loadItems("Amman")
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())




                .subscribe(new Consumer<ResultModel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(final ResultModel resultModel) throws Exception {

                        ARRAYS = resultModel.getCountryModels();


                        Realm.init(context);


                        Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
                        try {
                            // Do some network calls/etc and get some data and stuff it into a 'json' var

                            realm.beginTransaction();
                            realm.commitTransaction();

                            // At this point, the data in the UI thread is already up to date.
                            // ...
                        } finally {
                            realm.close();

                        }
                    }
```

This is my code in MainActivity :

```
 Realm.init(getApplicationContext());
    // ... boilerplate omitted for brevity
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    // get all the customers
    customers = realm.where(CountryModel.class).findAllAsync();
    //realm.beginTransaction();



    customers.addChangeListener(new OrderedRealmCollectionChangeListener<RealmResults<CountryModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<CountryModel> countryModels, OrderedCollectionChangeSet changeSet) {

            Log.e("Maher",countryModels.get(5).getCity());
        }
    });
```

NOTE: When I go back the realm prints change data but not in the background or realtime change.

Comment: `// go do some network calls/etc and get some data and stuff it into a 'json' var` if this is true then your app should crash with `NetworkOnMainThreadException` unless you have overridden StrictMode which is like, super bad.

Comment: Yes I went to make a call and my app work slow ( Breakdown) , can you explain the problem ?

Comment: please anyone help me! why change data is not syn ?

Comment: Yes you are running network call on UI thread

Comment: plaese can you help me ! I work a week ago on this problem , how i can the data change in background !

Comment: I mean, I don't know if you're doing this in onCreate, onStart, onResume, etc. so I can't possibly tell you what you are doing wrong.